# How to parse time 'HH:MM:SS' and display steps on xAxis every minute in Chart.js

Tags: javascript, charts, chart.js

I have got this chart created:

```
var chart = new Chart(ctx, {
        type: 'line',
                data: {
                        labels: ['00:00:00', '00:03:00', '00:06:00', '00:09:00'],
                        datasets: [{
                                label: 'somelabel',
                                data: [4333, 2344, 3343, 3444, 2123],
                    }]
                },
                options: {
                }
                });
```

As You can see, `labels` contains an array with strings which determinate particular time in format: `HH:MM:SS`, on X axis.

Chart displays and now I have got steps on xAxis the same as they are in `labels` array, however i would like to set step size **every minute** on this X axis, like: 00:00:00, 00:01:00, 00:02:00 etc., not 00:00:00', '00:03:00', '00:06:00', '00:09:00.

(I'm guessing need to parse date firstly)

Comment: how many labels do you want? im thinking a function that takes start time and a number of ticks....this could be written easily

Comment: Yes, lets say i want 60minutes

Comment: was my solution correct?

Answer (score 0):

Ok here you go, takes the 2 arguments specified in the comments, and assumes a reasonable version of JS is running.

```
function getTicks(startTime, count) {
    let ticks = [],
        date = startTime;
    for (let x = 0; x < count; x++) {
        let hours = date.getHours().toString(),
            mins = date.getMinutes().toString(),
            seconds = date.getSeconds().toString();

        date = new Date(date.getTime() + 60000);
        ticks.push(`${hours.padStart(2, '0')}:${mins.padStart(2, '0')}:${seconds.padStart(2, '0')}`);
    }

    return ticks;
}
```